# Access complete zone file of a ccTLD (.tk, .cf, .ga, and .ml)

Tags: dns, phishing

I am trying to find a method to detect phishing domains from some ccTLD such as .tk, .cf, .ml and .ga.

- Many of domains from these ccTLDs do not have Certificate Transparency (CT), so the method of using CT cannot help.
- These ccTLDs do not provide public zone file access, so I cannot extract them using zone file transfer too.
- There are some services such as zonefiles.io, viewdns.info/data, etc. However, their data is too late. I want to construct an almost real-time detection, thus want to get hourly or daily zone file access.
- One method is to use passive DNS but it may collect data too late (passive DNS can get the domains means that some victim already tried to access the page).
  I tried to contact with Root DNS of these ccTLDs but there is no response for a week.
  I wonder if you can give me some suggestion.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking is possible, although the whole idea of CT is new to me - thank you!

Comment: The way other filtering services run seems to rely on passive detection. It's impossible to tell if the naked and www record is just a legit parking page, while an unknown subdomain serves a phishing site.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with getting access to a zone file of .tk, .ga and others?

I am now working on the same thing. Sort of antiphishing project to detect phishing checking emerging domains almost in a real time.

Seems like tk, ga, ml, gq, pw -- are the most popular among the phishing compaigns. I think Freenom might have zone file of these ccTLD, but they also don't answer me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).